# WordPress integration with Zapier: Error fetching post status

Tags: wordpress, integration, zapier

Whenever I publish a new post, I should get a new record in google sheets. If I use my first WordPress account with it, the whole zap works fine, but if I use my second WordPress account, it gives me an error in the Post Status field. It also fails the test of the trigger as it says that it cannot find a post on the WordPress account.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/8RSEV.png

https://i.stack.imgur.com/rhaX4.png

I have tried everything mentioned on zapier help docs. I have contacted zapier support to help me with this. I have posted this query on zapier community as well. No luck till now. What I have identified from the error is that it has something to do with INCAPSULA(recaptcha), disturbing the communication between zapier and WordPress. Please help me with this.

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way forward is to log a support ticket to check the backend logs:

https://zapier.com/app/get-help

You'll likely want to make sure that:

- There are no caching and security plugins are activated
- No CDN (like Cloudflare) using any rules to block requests
- Add a NEW WordPress connection with the account in question (feel free to first log into Zapier via an incognito browser, before adding a new WordPress connection)

Thanks!